# Find a decimal with a precision of 2 using yes pattern|no pattern

Tags: python, python-re, decimal-precision

Can someone please point out the mistake I am making, why 123 is not matching here?

```
def is_decimal(num):
    import re
    pattern = re.compile(r"(\b\d+\.)(?(1)\d{1,2}\b|\d+)")
    result = pattern.search(num)
    return bool(result)


print(is_decimal('123.11'))
print(is_decimal('123'))
print(is_decimal('0.21'))

print(is_decimal('123.1214'))
print(is_decimal('e666.86'))
```

expected output: `True, True, True, False, False`

actual output :  `True, False, True, False, False`

Comment: You forgot to make the `.`. optional

Comment: It's not even clear what type of decimal you wish to match and which you do not. You should also mention the pattern you want the desired numbers to follow .

Comment: As @mousetail said, `(\b\d+\.)` matches `123.` and not `123`, `.` is included in the capture group

Answer (score 0):

try `pattern = re.compile(r"(\b\d+\.*)(?(1)\d{1,2}\b|\d+)")`

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following pattern:

```
^(\d+)(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

One of the key is to not use `\b` since the dot (`.`) is also considered as a word boundary which causes false parsing. Instead, you may use `^` to match the start of the string and `$` the end of the string.

The above pattern can be tested interactively at the following website:

https://regex101.com/r/CixCHT/4